# Why does setBackground cover other drawing?

Tags: java, swing, drawing, setbackground

i have the following code:

```
    private void ConvertButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(50, 100, 200));
    Graphics g = getGraphics();
    g.drawString("tekst", 120, 120); 
    g.drawLine(175, 175, 140, 140); 
    g.setColor(Color.yellow); 
    g.fillOval(190, 120, 160, 160); 
    g.setColor(Color.red); 
    g.drawRoundRect(190, 110, 150, 120, 115, 115);  
}
```

I want it to paint the form (after pressing the button) in the appropriate way, but what happens instead is it paints only the background after the first click and after the second click it paints the rest of the objects.
When i try this approach instead, with overriding paint method:

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
    setBackground(new Color(50, 100, 200));       
    g.drawString("tekst", 120, 120); 
    g.drawLine(175, 175, 140, 140); 
    g.setColor(Color.yellow); 
    g.fillOval(190, 120, 160, 160); 
    g.setColor(Color.red); 
    g.drawRoundRect(190, 110, 150, 120, 115, 115);  
}
```

and having

```
private void ConvertButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    repaint();  
}
```

then the background is of grey color instead of blue and the button disappears (appears only after i have the mouse right over it).

So, finally my question is: What exactly is wrong with both of these examples (i want to understand both, since this is only a learning exercise i'd like to know what is happening rather than simply finding a solution), and which approach is better? Thanks in advance, i hope I didn't miss a similar question on this site, if i did i'm sorry!

Comment: Actually, you should never ever call `setBackground()` or set other properties from within `paint()` or `paintComponent()`, as that will trigger a `PropertyChange` event, that will cause an immediate `repaint()` of the component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Graphics g = getGraphics();
```

Don't use getGraphics() to do custom painting. That type of painting is only temporary and will be lost the next time Swing repaints the component. Also, don't override the paint() method. To set the background Color of a component you just do:

```
component.setBackground(...);
```

Custom painting is done by overriding the paintComponent() method of your custom component. Don't forget to invoke super.paintComponent() at the start. Read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information.

Comment: Ok thx for commenting both pieces of code. One question though, i overrode the paint method instead of paintComponent because my component (it extends JFrame fyi) doesn't seem to inherit paintComponent. I looked up JFrame at the API and it doesn't inherit it either if i'm not mistaken? So what am i missing and how exactly should i override the paintComponent method? Thx in advance!

Comment: You should NOT be extending JFrame. The proper way to build a GUI in Swing is to add components to the frame. You can extend any component that you add to the frame, but there is no need to extend JFrame. Read the Swing tutorial and look at any example in the tutorial. None of the examples extend JFrame.

Comment: But they do extend JFrame in the tutorial, for example in a Celsius converter program all the code is in the class "CelsiusConverterGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame". Is this not ok, and why? Also, if JFrame doesn't have paintComponent, then where exactly should I override the paintComponent method? Thx in advance again, I appreciate Your help.

Comment: That is a Netbeans tutorial, not a Swing tutorial. I gave you the link to use for custom painting 3 hours ago!

Answer (score 2):

The method where you override paint is correct, you should use:

```
g.setColor(new Color(50, 100, 200));
g.fillRect(0, 0, c.getWidth(),c.getHeight());
```

instead of:

```
setBackground(new Color(50, 100, 200));
```

Or alternatively set the background color and in your paint() method, call the super implementation before painting anything else:

```
super.paint(g);
```